# Is there a way to mark the page I was left on in Foxit?

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

I am not talking about the bookmark function, but a way to "keep reading" from where I left without needing to remember the page I was left on. Like a favorite page function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  a feature for saving and restoring session.

You can configure like so:

Foxit Reader -> go to "**File**"->**Preferences** -> **History** >tick **Restore last session when application starts** and see if this option is what you're looking for

See below:

[image: foxit reader]

More information please check here: https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/